# Swiftmailer - sends mail twice without any content

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, swiftmailer

I uses the swiftmailer for sending a mail.

My code is:

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/swift_mailer/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.---.com', 25)
                              ->setUsername('----')
                              ->setPassword('---');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
/* database queries  */
$get_count = $this->db->query("SELECT client_id, email FROM `tbl_client`")->result();
foreach($get_count as $count) {
    $id = $count->client_id;
    $c_email = $count->email;
    $today_leads = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) leads_count FROM `tbl_leads` WHERE DATE(leads_update_on) = curdate() AND client_id = $id")->row();
    $today_leads = $today_leads->leads_count;
    $till_date = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) leads_till_date FROM `tbl_leads` WHERE client_id = $id")->row_array();
    $till_date_leads = $till_date['leads_till_date'];

    $get_project = $this->db->query("SELECT p.project_id, p.project_name FROM `tbl_project` p INNER JOIN tbl_client c ON p.client_id = c.client_id WHERE  c.client_id = $id")->result();

    if((count($get_project) )> 0 ){
        foreach($get_project as $project) {
             $project_name = $project->project_name;
             $project_id = $project->project_id;
             $source_count = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) count_source, source FROM `tbl_leads` WHERE DATE(leads_update_on) = curdate() AND project_id=$project_id AND client_id=$id  GROUP BY source")->result();
             if((count($source_count) )> 0){
                ob_start();
                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/views/email_templates/daily_leads_cron.php');
                $body123 = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();

                //echo $body123;exit;

                $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Daily Report")
                                        ->setFrom(array('abc@xyz.in' => 'abc'))
                                        ->setTo(array($c_email))
                                        ->setBody($body123, 'text/html')
                ;
                $mailer->send($message);
            }
    }
}
else {
    echo "else";
}
}
```

In `daily_leads_cron.php` there is html file with `php foreach`loop. I've tested the output of `daily_leads_cron.php` file with `//echo $body123;exit;` and its working fine.

The problem is that the receiver of mail gets two email instead of one and those mails are `BLANK` without any content. I've tested all loops and there is no any error. Anybody can tell me why this happening.

Comment: Does it work to add a text body and a separate part for the html body? 
`->setBody($text123);
$message->addPart($body123, 'text/html');`

Comment: No. Its working as earlier

Comment: Does it work if you use `->setBody($body123)` without 'text/html'?

Comment: I tried but still its blank

Comment: is there any problem with `ob_start()` `require_once()` `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: I am not sure, but since `echo $body123;` works for you, `ob_start()` and the rest are probably ok. Try changing `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/vie...` to `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/vie...` so that it is included each loop, not just the first time.

Comment: That's  great..! The error was actually because of `require_once`